# Storyboards not compiling in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
CompileStoryboard Ten/AppLaunchStoryboard~ipad.storyboard
cd /Users/user/Documents/ten.ios
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module Ten --output-partial-info-plist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ten-cggfgkxskhslfueivajzyloajadz/Build/Intermediates/Ten.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ten.build/AppLaunchStoryboard~ipad-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ten-cggfgkxskhslfueivajzyloajadz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ten.app /Users/user/Documents/ten.ios/Ten/AppLaunchStoryboard~ipad.storyboard

2015-06-26 11:59:11.459 ibtoold[42192:13214893] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-8121.20/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/Platform/IBIdiom.m:105
Details:  Assertion failed: !
Object:   <IBIPadIdiom: 0x7fe18ce41100>
Method:   -filePathWithTargetDeviceSuffixForBaseFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe18a714480>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010ac05cf5 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010ac05829 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010ac05a40 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010ac059a2 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010bd00df1 -[IBIdiom filePathWithTargetDeviceSuffixForBaseFilePath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000011536276b (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000010bbd0381 -[IBDocument finishCompilingWithOutputPath:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x000000010a9c3ff6 (in ibtoold)
  8  0x000000010a9c64dc (in ibtoold)
  9  0x000000010a9c9f15 (in ibtoold)
 10  0x000000010a9ca5c9 (in ibtoold)
 11  0x000000010a9ca4a0 (in ibtoold)
 12  0x000000010a9b9bab (in ibtoold)
 13  0x000000010a9c9b0a (in ibtoold)
 14  0x000000010a9c8d6f (in ibtoold)
 15  0x00007fff8464e5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Hi,
I'm trying to build my App for iOS 9 using Xcode 7 beta 2, however most of my storyboards are not compiling. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this too and it seems that it doesn't like the "~" in a storyboard name. Try renaming the storyboard without a ~